# Get nth element from numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have a numpy array of rgb-imagetype looking like this:

```
d = [ [ [0, 1, 2],    [3, 4, 5],    [6 ,7 ,8] ], 
      [ [9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14], [15, 16 ,17] ],
      [ [18,19, 20], [21, 22, 23], [24, 25 ,26] ] ]
```

I select a few random r/g or b pixels using `random`

```
import random
r = random.sample(range(1, len(d)*len(d[0])*3), 3)
# for example r = [25, 4, 15]
```

How can I then select the data I want?

Like I want `25th value in array d` for the first `r_value = 25` which corresponds to `d[2][2][1]`, because it is the 25th value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to inspect/alter the array linearly on a frequent basis, you can **construct a linear view**:

```
d_lin = d.reshape(-1)  # construct a 1d view
d_lin[25]         # access the 25-th element
```

Or putting it all in a one-liner:

```
d.reshape(-1)[25]  # construct a 1d view
```

You can from now on access (and modify) the elements in `d_view` as a 1d array. So you access the 25-th value with `d_lin[25]`. You don't have to construct a new view each time you want to access/modify an element: simply reuse the `d_lin` view.

Furthermore the *order* of flattening can be specified (`order='C'` (C-like), `order='F'` (Fortran-like) or `order='A'` (Fortran-wise if contiguous in meory, C-like otherwise)). `order='F'` means that we first iterate over the greatest dimension.

The advantage of a view (but this can also lead to unintended behavior), is that if you assign a new value through `d_lin`, like **`d_lin[25] = 3`, it will alter the original matrix**.

Alternatives are [`.flat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flat.html), or [`np.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html). So the following are somewhat equivalent:

```
d.reshape(-1)[25]
np.ravel(d)[25]
d.flat[25]
```

There are however some differences between the `reshape(..)` and `ravel(..)` approach against the `flat` approach. The most important one is the fact that `d.flat` does *not* create a full view. Indeed if we for instance want to pass the view to another function that expects a numpy array, then it will crash, for example:

```
>>> d.flat.sum()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'numpy.flatiter' object has no attribute 'sum'
>>> d.reshape(-1).sum()
351
>>> np.ravel(d).sum()
351
```

This is not *per se* a problem. If we want to limit the number of tools (for instance as a protection mechanism), then this will actually give us a bit more security (although we can still set elements elements in bulk, and call `np.sum(..)` on an `flatiter` object).

Comment: This is exaxtly what I wanted, since I want to alter the original matrix. Thank you

Comment: With the `flat` iterator, I don't think there's any speed advantage to constructing a separate `view`.  `d.flat` indexing may actually be faster than the unraveled equivalent.

Comment: @hpaulj: I think the advantage of a view is that it "acts" like an array. You can for instance calculate the `sum()` over it, or inspect the `shape`. This can be useful if you for instance have some methods that work on array-like objects. In other words, one can treat it as 1d array as if it was never a 3d array.

Comment: I think [hpaulj's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44764767/2668831) is probably a better solution than this, [`numpy.flat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flat.html) makes this 3 liner into a single attribute reference

Comment: @LouisMaddox: furthermore something that was noted in the comments, and now in the answer, is that `d.flat` does *not* produce a fully flat view of the array. For instance we can not calculate the `.sum()` of `.flat`. This can be problematic if we want to pass a flat view to a function, and that function expects an *array-like* object. With `.flat`, it will return a `flatiter` object, which has a more limited number of tools.

Answer (score 5):

What you want to do is index it as a flat or 1d array.  There are various ways of doing this.  `ravel` and `reshape(-1)` create 1d views, `flatten()` creates a 1d copy.

The most efficient is the [`flat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flat.html) iterator (an attribute, not method):

```
In [347]: d.flat[25]
Out[347]: 25
```

(it can be used in an assignment as well, eg. `d.flat[25]=0`.

```
In [341]: idx = [25, 4, 15]
In [343]: d.flat[idx]
Out[343]: array([25,  4, 15])
```

To find out what the 3d index is, there's utility, `unravel_index` (and a corresponding `ravel_multi_index`)

```
In [344]: fidx=np.unravel_index(idx,d.shape)
In [345]: fidx
Out[345]: 
(array([2, 0, 1], dtype=int32),
 array([2, 1, 2], dtype=int32),
 array([1, 1, 0], dtype=int32))
In [346]: d[fidx]
Out[346]: array([25,  4, 15])
```

This a tuple, the index for one element is read 'down', e.g. (2,2,1).

---

On a large array, `flat` indexing is actually a bit faster:

```
In [362]: dl=np.ones((100,100,100))
In [363]: idx=np.arange(0,1000000,40)
In [364]: fidx=np.unravel_index(idx,dl.shape)
In [365]: timeit x=dl[fidx]
1000 loops, best of 3: 447 µs per loop
In [366]: timeit x=dl.flat[idx]
1000 loops, best of 3: 312 µs per loop
```

Comment: Very useful answer with some more numpy tools I didn't know of. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.flatten` method, like this:

```
a = np.array(d)
d[25] # print 26
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not want to flatten your array:
if you know the size of the sublists beforehand, you can easily calculate it out. In your example, every element of the main list is a list of exactly 3 elements, each element containing 3. So to access `n` you could do something like

`i = n//9
j = (n%9)//3
k = (n%3)
element = d[i][j][k]`

For `n=25`, you'd get `i = 2, j = 2, k = 1`, just as you wanted.

In python2, you can (and have to) use the normal `/` operator instead of `//`

Comment: `np.unravel_index` does this calculation.

Answer (score -1):

If you only care on the value, you can flatten your array, and access it directly as

```
val = d.flatten()[r]
```

If you really want the index corresponding to the flattened index, you need to something like this:

```
ix_2 = r % d.shape[2]
helper_2 = (r - ix_2) / d.shape[2]
ix_1 = helper_2 % d.shape[1]
helper_1 = (helper_2 - ix_1) / d.shape[1]
ix_0 = helper_1 % d.shape[0]

val = d[ix_0, ix_1, ix_2]
```

Comment: `flatten()` produces a copy, not a view.