# Use global positions to mutate list, in list of lists

Tags: python, list

I need to keep my data in a list of lists, but want to edit elements in the lists based on their overall position.

For instance:

```
mylist = [['h','e','l','l','o'], ['w','o','r','l','d']]
```

I want to change position 5 as if it was all one list resulting in:

```
[['h','e','l','l','o'], ['change','o','r','l','d']]
```

This is for very large lists and lots of mutations so speed is essential!

Comment: If speed is essential, maybe start by not using lists? Your problem seems more suited to numpy arrays, which allow acces in the way you're talking about by changing their shape. By the way, if your lists are of varying and unordered length, you'll have to obtain their length to properly index, and if you really have a lot of mutations, you would do well to keep a record of those lengths instead of having to look them up every time

Comment: Thanks! I suspected it might need to be done recursively with an index of the lengths

Comment: Are the sublists of constant (equal) length? As @grismar says, this can be done easily with [numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44759527/get-nth-element-from-numpy-array), but for a list of lists you'll need to create a lookup table with the sublist lengths.

Comment: All of different lengths. I was hoping to find a workaround from having to determine the length of each first to then mutate based on the overall position (as if they were all one list)

Comment: Recursion would only (perhaps) be beneficial if the nesting of lists continues on multiple levels. You should provide more information about what the actual dataset would look like for useful suggestions. Also, would these lists be of variable length in the sense that their length might change? Or is their length fixed, but varying between lists?

Comment: Are you want to change one position at a time or multiple position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution of your's question

```
# initializing list
input_list = [['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'], ['w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']]

print("The initial list is : " + str(input_list))

length: int = 0

# define position(global index) where you want to update items in list
change_index = 5

## global starting index of sublist [0,5]
sub_list_start_index: list = list()

for sub_list in input_list:
    sub_list_start_index.append(length)
    length += len(sub_list)

    # check if index we want to change is <= global list index and
    if change_index <= length - 1 and change_index >= max(sub_list_start_index):
        sub_list_index = int(change_index - max(sub_list_start_index))
        input_list[input_list.index(sub_list)][sub_list_index] = 'change'

print("Updated list : " + str(input_list))
```

Output:

```
The initial list is : [['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'], ['w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']]
Updated list : [['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'], ['change', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']]
```